# ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib Unexpected end of archive

Tags: zip, filestream, memorystream

All,
 I'm trying to look for files in a directory zip them into a stream then put them in another directory. In zips the file but I get unexpected end of archive. Any help would be great.

They pass in

strReport 'name of report

strUser 'folder to search

strReportNameSearch 'What files to search

```
Dim strReports() As String
    Dim thefiles As Array
    Dim strZipFileName As String
    Dim dateTimeNow As String = DateTime.Now
    Dim dateOnlyString As String = dateTimeNow.ToString
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(4095) {}
    Try


        strReports = Split(strReport, "/") 'strReports(0) strReports(1)

            strZipFileName = "xxx.zip"

        Dim outStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        Using zipOutputStream As New ZipOutputStream(outStream)
            zipOutputStream.SetLevel(9)
            thefiles = Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ReportLookup").ToString() & strUser, strReportNameSearch & "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            For Each fileName As String In thefiles
                Dim fs As Stream = File.OpenRead(fileName)
                Dim entry As New ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(fileName))
                entry.Size = fs.Length
                zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry)

                Dim count As Integer = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
                While count > 0
                    zipOutputStream.Write(Buffer, 0, count)
                    count = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
                    If Not Response.IsClientConnected Then
                        Exit While
                    End If
                    Response.Flush()
                End While
                fs.Close()
            Next
            zipOutputStream.Flush()
            outStream.Flush()

            Dim wholezip As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ReportLookup").ToString() & strReport & "\" & strZipFileName
            If (File.Exists(wholezip)) Then
                File.Delete(wholezip)
            End If
            Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(wholezip, FileMode.Create)
                'outStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                outStream.Position = 0

                outStream.CopyTo(fs)

            End Using
            zipOutputStream.Close()

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExceptionManager.Publish(ex)
    End Try
```

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of trial an error this worked

Using zf As FileStream = New FileStream(wholezip, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
                ' Using zf As FileStream = File.Create(wholezip)
                'open zip stream
                Using zipOutputStream As New ZipOutputStream(zf)
                    zipOutputStream.SetLevel(9) 'set compression level
                    'get files
                    thefiles = Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ReportLookup").ToString() & strUser, strReportNameSearch & "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                    'loop thru files
                    For Each fileName As String In thefiles
                        Dim zentry As ZipEntry = New ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(fileName))
                        zentry.IsUnicodeText = True
                        zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(zentry)
                        'count bytes
                        Using streamReader As FileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName)
                            Dim count As Integer = streamReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                            While count > 0
                                zipOutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count)
                                count = streamReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                            End While
                        End Using
                    Next
                End Using
            End Using